# Jquery UI Modal form Dialog not blocking background

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am implementing Jquery UI Popup modal form except that it is not blocking the bckground page. the code i am using is as follows:

```
 <link href="../../Content/css/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () { $("#Form").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 600, width: 800, modal: true }); });


            $("#btnOpen").click(function () {
                $("#Form").dialog("open");
            });


        });
```

I am opening on button click btnOpen. Please help

Comment: Hi Avinash, I too have the same issue. Could you please let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: @Usham..The cause for this problem is very simple. In my case, it is the problem with CSS files and script files. So, make sure that you have properly referenced all your script files and CSS in correct order. This would definitely help...Good Luck..